# Multiple artifacts issue with deploying zip to nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus

My program outputs a zip and I want to deploy this zip to the nexus repository. I am using gradle as build system.

Fragment of my configuration:

```
class DestinationFileTask extends DefaultTask {
    File destFile;
}

task generate(type: DestinationFileTask) {
    destFile = file('output/file.zip')
}

artifacts {
    output generate.destFile
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "url")
            pom.version = "1.01-SNAPSHOT"
            pom.artifactId = "ID"
            pom.groupId = "com.test.test"
        }
    }
}
```

When I am executing gradle `uploadArchives` I am receiving this error:

```
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > A POM cannot have multiple artifacts with the same type and classifier. Already have MavenArtifact ID:zip:zip:null, trying to add MavenArtifact ID:zip:zip:null.
```

Even when I try to do this for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while working on Gradle upgrade:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':registry:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > A POM cannot have multiple artifacts with the same type and classifier. Already have MavenArtifact registry:zip:zip:null, trying to add MavenArtifact registry:zip:zip:null.
```

Gradle upgrade it self has nothing to do with the error its more related to the plugins you are using.
The error is really misleading and there is not much info on Google about it as well.

But it turns out that the cause of this error is Maven trying to upload artifact on top of the other one.
So first of all check what packaging tasks you are executing, in my case:

```
task ':registry:bootDistTar',
task ':registry:bootDistZip',
...
task ':registry:distTar',
task ':registry:distZip',
```

The workaround to fix it is to change the classifier (in my case for spring boot app):

```
bootDistTar {
  classifier = 'bootTar'
}

bootDistZip {
  classifier = 'bootZip'
}
```

Hope this will help for someone else as it was quite hard to figure out.
[Github issue where I found the workaround.](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin/issues/58)